# Load custom JS files in specific view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, kineticjs

I have a view that has a diagram tool implemented in JS using kineticjs and I want to load the JS files just in a specific view.
I have done this:

In the view:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "diagrams" %>
<% end %>
```

The manifest js file named diagrams.js:

```
//= require diagramtool/kinetic
//= require diagramtool/diagramtool0
//= require diagramtool/diagramtool1
//= require diagramtool/diagramtool2
```

The application.js file (removed the require_tree):

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

The layout, application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Realyzor</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

And added this line in config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( diagrams.js )
```

And my problem is that, in order to get the files loaded I have to go to the view and refresh the page.

Why do I have to go to the view and then refresh the page to get the JS files loaded?

Why the JS files are not load when I go to the view?

I'm using rails 4.1.5

Comment: Have you read about how turbolinks works? It does not reload the head of your html pages when you click on links to improve performance. I'm not sure how to do what you want, but the reason it only works after page reload is turbolinks.

Comment: Yeah, you should just put your diagrams js file in the application.js manifest and let the Asset pipeline concatenate it all together in production. It will get served once and cached in the browser anyway.